# An induction proof of inequation related to $e$ and factorial

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, induction

We have:

$T_{n} = nT_{n-1} + 1 $
$T_{2} = 5$

$$Prove:T_{n} \leq \lceil n!e \rceil $$

I only know how to deal with the induction like
$T_{n} = aT_{n-1} + b (a, b\in R)$

But really don't know how to deal with the induction with g(n) in front of $T_{n-1}$

Could you give me some hints?

I'd really appreciate it!

Here is What I tried:

$\frac{T_{n}}{n} = T_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}$

Trying to relate $e$ with $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n}$

#### Thanks to marty cohen's guidance Here is one solution.

- Hint1:  $e$ also has connection with $\prod_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$
- Hint2: $T_{n} = a(n)T_{n-1} + b(n)$ can be transfer into another induction formular by introducing $A(n) = \prod_{k=m}^{n}a(n)$

Solution:
$\frac{T_{n}}{n!} = \frac{T_{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{1}{n!}$
By induction: $\frac{T_{n}}{n!} = \frac{T_{2}}{2!} + \sum_{1=3}^{n}\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{5}{2} + \sum_{i=3}^{n}\frac{1}{n!} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n!} \le \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} = $e$ $

Comment: Note that the $T_n = nT_{n-1}$ is pretty similar to the factorial function.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and I tried $T_{n} / n = T_{n-1} + 1 / n$, I think 1 / n is related to e

Comment: Also notice that $2!$ is 2, while $T_n$ is 5, and dividing them gives $2.5$, which is smaller than $e$.

Comment: Maybe try subbing that in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the recurrence
$T_{n} = a(n)T_{n-1} + b(n)
$,
(here
$a(n)=n$ and $b(n)=1$),
one way
(this can be considered a "trick")
is to let
$A(n)
=\prod_{k=m}^n a(k)
$
($m$ is where the
recurrence starts)
and divide the recurrence by
$A(n)$.
It then becomes

$\dfrac{T_{n}}{A(n)} 
= \dfrac{a(n)T_{n-1}}{A(n)} + \dfrac{b(n)}{A(n)}
= \dfrac{T_{n-1}}{A(n-1)} + \dfrac{b(n)}{A(n)}
$
since
$\dfrac{A(n)}{a(n)}
=A(n-1)$.

Letting
$U(n)
=\dfrac{T_{n}}{A(n)}
$,
this becomes
$U(n)
=U(n-1)+ \dfrac{b(n)}{A(n)}
$
which can be directly solved
by telescoping.

In this case,
$A(n)
=\prod_{k=2}^n k
=n!
$
and
$\dfrac{b(n)}{A(n)}
=\dfrac1{n!}
$,
so this shows where the
$e$ comes from.

I'll let you fill in the details.

Comment: Great Idea, Thanks for sharing your wisdom!            In this problem we have $\frac{T_{n}}{n!} = \frac{T_{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{1}{n!}$             By Induction: $\frac{T_{n}}{n!} = \frac{T_{2}}{2!} + (\frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + ... + \frac{1}{n!})$            Then need to improve $\frac{5}{2} + \frac{1}{3!} + .... + \frac{1}{n!} \leq e$                  But we only know that $\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} = e$ But $\frac{5}{2} = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}$                  Maybe there is something wrong with the problem? Or maybe we have to make full use of the upper bound?

Comment: We also have $e = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n!}$ and $\dfrac25 < \dfrac12$.

Comment: Oh, I made a silly mistake, I'll correct it at once. Thank you for your tender guidance, I wish you a really great day!